# Score/Predict a large dataset using Dask with Lightgbm

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Looking to use a dask distributed cluster to speed up lightgbm scoring/predictions. Essentially looking for the equivalent of ParallelPostFit for lightgbm-- currently appears to only work with sklearn models https://examples.dask.org/machine-learning/parallel-prediction.html

Does anybody know what the lightgbm equivalent is?

Answer (score 1):

In the time since this question was first ask, `dask-lightgbm` has been absorbed into `lightgbm` and `dask-lightgbm` has been archived.

`lightgbm` (the official Python package for LightGBM), provides interfaces for training and prediction using Dask.

See https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parallel-Learning-Guide.html#prediction-with-dask for documentation or https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/fdc582ea6ba13faf15ee6707c7c7542790c8821d/examples/python-guide/dask/prediction.py for a code example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these two?

- [dask-lightgbm](https://github.com/dask/dask-lightgbm)
- [xgboost-dask](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/dask.html)

Comment: have tinkered with dask-lightgbm that looks to be for training not predictions

Comment: So you have already a trained model and you want to use it to predict? Is this going to be on a cluster or on a local machine?

Comment: That's right I have a trained lightgbm model and a large dataset that typically takes an hour to predict locally ie not using dask. I have a serverless dask cluster deployed on AWS I'm able to connect to via Client. Am I able to use this distributed cluster when calling .predict on the model?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the model and wrap it in ParallelPostFit